# spring boot automatically create database schema Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using Spring boot and when I trying to run and generate tables, I don't have any results in my database Oracle.

Here is my `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
# Set true for first time db initialization.
spring.datasource.initialize=true

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.22:1521:DRUGSTORE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.22:1521/DRUGSTORE
spring.datasource.username=PHARM
spring.datasource.password=PHARM
spring.datasource.schema-password=PHARM
spring.datasource.schema-username=PHARM
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = PHARM
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=oracle
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=7
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=20
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Here is a sample entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable; import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADRESSE")
public class Adresse implements Serializable{
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="ID_ADRESSE",length=255)
    private BigDecimal idAdresse;
    @Column(name="LINE_1",length=255)
    private String line1;
    @Column(name="LINE_2",length=255)
    private String line2;
    @Column(name="LINE_3",length=255)
    private String line3;
    @Column(name="LONGITUDE",length=255)
    private Double longitude;
    @Column(name="LATITUDE",length=255)
    private Double latitude;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Ville.class)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Ville ville;
    @Column(name="CREATE_DATE",length=50)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate ;
    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATE" ,length=50)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdate ;

    public String getLine1() {
        return line1;
    }
    public void setLine1(String line1) {
        this.line1 = line1;
    }
    public String getLine2() {
        return line2;
    }
    public void setLine2(String line2) {
        this.line2 = line2;
    }
    public String getLine3() {
        return line3;
    }
    public void setLine3(String line3) {
        this.line3 = line3;
    }
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public Ville getVille() {
        return ville;
    }
    public void setVille(Ville ville) {
        this.ville = ville;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }
    public BigDecimal getIdAdresse() {
        return idAdresse;
    }
    public void setIdAdresse(BigDecimal idAdresse) {
        this.idAdresse = idAdresse;
    }
    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }
    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }
    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
    public Adresse(String line1, String line2, String line3, Double 
        longitude, Double latitude, Ville ville,Date createDate ,Date
        lastUpdate) {
        super();
        this.line1 = line1;
        this.line2 = line2;
        this.line3 = line3;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.ville = ville;
        this.lastUpdate=lastUpdate;
        this.createDate =createDate;
    }
    public Adresse() {
        super();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in the console. it would be helpful if you could share the stack-trace .

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

with

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```